# Books on moral realism and moral relativism?

Tags: ethics, reference-request

Does anyone know any good books on the topic of moral realism / moral relativism? The kind of book I would most prefer would be one that would address both (realism and relativism) from a completely objective point of view, discussing the "pros and cons" of both of them. Other sources are welcome too, but mainly I'm looking for a book/books.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "completely objective point of view, discussing the 'pros and cons' of them both."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the more commonly used chapters in ethics classes is James Rachels' chapter on Moral Relativism in *The Elements of Moral Philosophy*. It's a chapter explaining some of the basic difficulties faced by moral relativism as a palatable moral theory.

For defenses of [moral relativism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-relativism/), two of the more famous defenders are David Wong and David Velleman. Wong's book *Natural Moralities: A Defense of Pluralistic Relativism* (reviewed at [NDPR here](https://ndpr.nd.edu/news/25269-natural-moralities-a-defense-of-pluralistic-relativism/)).  I'm no as familiar with Vellerman's arguments.

Another think defending moral relativism is Gilbert Harman. See "Moral Relativism Defended" ([jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2184078?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)) and "Moral Relativism Explained" ([from his personal site](https://www.princeton.edu/~harman/Papers/Moral_Relativism.pdf)).

Returning to who doesn't agree with moral relativism: Plato, Aristotle, Kant, Mill, Locke, ... and most figures in the history of philosophy. A contemporary philosopher who argues against it is Peter Kreeft ([see here](http://www.peterkreeft.com/audio/05_relativism/relativism_transcription.htm)). Charles Taylor also rejects it at length in his books.

Answer (score 1):

"After Virtue" by Alasdair MacIntyre  is a major landmark in contemporary moral philosophy.  I don't know if it will answer your specific question but it's one of those works that count as required ready for anybody working in that area.